# D3.js bug on Android vs iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, d3.js

If you try going to this animated bezier curve D3.js animation website (https://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/), you can move the control points to change the trajectory of the curve. This works if you go to the website with iOS but you cannot move the control points on Android. Does anyone know why this is? Maybe a bug or implementation shortcoming for Android's WebView?

I'm trying to figure out if programming with Phonegap/Cordova is worth it and things like this make me think that the technology is not mature yet...

Comment: The issue you will have with hybrid apps is that all webviews are non-standard and (until recently) do not update independently from the OS. This is not a Cordova issue, this is a general issue with hybrid dev.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But at the end of the day, this breaks the app for the user. Bugs like this could be real "gotchas" against hybrid dev in general, including Cordova.

Comment: try the crosswalk plugin to get a good webview based on chromium for all android devices, android webview isn't very good on devices below 4.4

Comment: I'm on Android 5.0.1 and the bug is still there. There's another bug in that if I try to click a control point too much, one of the control points disappears and the app breaks even more because there is no longer any curve at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a cause of this problem is compatibility of the drag event with touch screen, and it is fixed in D3.js v3. Here shows a demo snippet mirroring the website, and the only change is loading a newer version of D3.js.

Since I'm using an emulator and only changing a specific little part without examining how the website actually works, this answer may not fully covering your problem.

```js
var w = 250,
    h = 300,
    t = .5,
    delta = .01,
    padding = 10,
    points = [{x: 10, y: 250}, {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 100, y: 0}, {x: 200, y: 250}, {x: 225, y: 125}],
    bezier = {},
    line = d3.svg.line().x(x).y(y),
    n = 4,
    stroke = d3.scale.category20b(),
    orders = d3.range(2, n + 2);

var vis = d3.select("#vis").selectAll("svg")
    .data(orders)
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", w + 2 * padding)
    .attr("height", h + 2 * padding)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding + ")");

update();

vis.selectAll("circle.control")
    .data(function(d) { return points.slice(0, d) })
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "control")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
      .on("dragstart", function(d) {
        this.__origin__ = [d.x, d.y];
      })
      .on("drag", function(d) {
        d.x = Math.min(w, Math.max(0, this.__origin__[0] += d3.event.dx));
        d.y = Math.min(h, Math.max(0, this.__origin__[1] += d3.event.dy));
        bezier = {};
        update();
        vis.selectAll("circle.control")
          .attr("cx", x)
          .attr("cy", y);
      })
      .on("dragend", function() {
        delete this.__origin__;
      }));

vis.append("text")
  .attr("class", "t")
  .attr("x", w / 2)
  .attr("y", h)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

vis.selectAll("text.controltext")
    .data(function(d) { return points.slice(0, d); })
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "controltext")
    .attr("dx", "10px")
    .attr("dy", ".4em")
    .text(function(d, i) { return "P" + i });

var last = 0;
d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
  t = (t + (elapsed - last) / 5000) % 1;
  last = elapsed;
  update();
});

function update() {
  var interpolation = vis.selectAll("g")
      .data(function(d) { return getLevels(d, t); });
  interpolation.enter().append("g")
      .style("fill", colour)
      .style("stroke", colour);

  var circle = interpolation.selectAll("circle")
      .data(Object);
  circle.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4);
  circle
      .attr("cx", x)
      .attr("cy", y);

  var path = interpolation.selectAll("path")
      .data(function(d) { return [d]; });
  path.enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
  path.attr("d", line);

  var curve = vis.selectAll("path.curve")
      .data(getCurve);
  curve.enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "curve");
  curve.attr("d", line);

  vis.selectAll("text.controltext")
      .attr("x", x)
      .attr("y", y);
  vis.selectAll("text.t")
      .text("t=" + t.toFixed(2));
}

function interpolate(d, p) {
  if (arguments.length < 2) p = t;
  var r = [];
  for (var i=1; i<d.length; i++) {
    var d0 = d[i-1], d1 = d[i];
    r.push({x: d0.x + (d1.x - d0.x) * p, y: d0.y + (d1.y - d0.y) * p});
  }
  return r;
}

function getLevels(d, t_) {
  if (arguments.length < 2) t_ = t;
  var x = [points.slice(0, d)];
  for (var i=1; i<d; i++) {
    x.push(interpolate(x[x.length-1], t_));
  }
  return x;
}

function getCurve(d) {
  var curve = bezier[d];
  if (!curve) {
    curve = bezier[d] = [];
    for (var t_=0; t_<=1; t_+=delta) {
      var x = getLevels(d, t_);
      curve.push(x[x.length-1][0]);
    }
  }
  return [curve.slice(0, t / delta + 1)];
}

function x(d) { return d.x; }
function y(d) { return d.y; }
function colour(d, i) {
  stroke(-i);
  return d.length > 1 ? stroke(i) : "red";
}
```

```css
body{font-size:1em;font-weight:400;word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;font-family:Verdana, Myriad Web, Syntax, sans-serif;font-size-adjust:.58;color:#000;background:#FFF;line-height:1.58em;border-top:0;border-left:0;border-bottom:0;border-right:0;width:auto;margin:1.58em 5% 1.58em 8%;padding:0}small{font-size:.92em}big{font-size:1.17em}pre{font-family:Monotype.com, Courier New, monospace;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;line-height:1.25em;border-left:0;border-right:0;margin:.75em 0;padding:0}ol li{list-style-type:decimal}ol ol li{list-style-type:lower-alpha}ol ol ol li{list-style-type:lower-roman}table,tbody,tr,td{font-size:1em;word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;font-family:Verdana, Myriad Web, Syntax, sans-serif;font-size-adjust:.58}h1{font-family:Myriad Web, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size-adjust:.48;font-size:2em;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-align:left;margin:1.33em 0 .33em;padding:0}h2{font-family:Myriad Web, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size-adjust:.48;font-size:1.75em;font-weight:500;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-align:left;margin:1.75em 0 .33em;padding:0}h3{font-family:Myriad Web, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size-adjust:.48;font-size:1.58em;font-weight:500;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-align:left;margin:1.58em 0 .33em;padding:0}h4{font-family:Myriad Web, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size-adjust:.48;font-size:1.33em;font-weight:500;font-style:oblique;text-decoration:none;word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-align:left;margin:1.33em 0 .33em;padding:0}h5,dt{font-family:Myriad Web, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size-adjust:.48;font-size:1.17em;font-weight:500;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none}h6{font-family:Myriad Web, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size-adjust:.48;font-size:1em;font-weight:500;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-align:left;margin:1em 0 .33em;padding:0}tfoot,thead{font-size:1em;word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;font-family:Myriad Web, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size-adjust:.48}th{vertical-align:baseline;font-size:1em;font-weight:700;word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;font-family:Myriad Web, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size-adjust:.48;text-align:left}hr{visibility:visible;color:#000;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;height:1px;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-align:left;width:100%;margin:.75em 0;padding:0}a,address,blockquote,body,cite,code,dd,del,dfn,div,dl,dt,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,iframe,img,kbd,li,object,ol,p,q,samp,small,span,strong,ul,var,applet,big,center,dir,font,hr,menu,pre,abbr,acronym,bdo,button,fieldset,ins,label{word-spacing:normal;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;text-decoration:none;border-color:#000;border-style:none}strong{font-style:italic;background:#FFF;font-weight:700;color:#000}em strong,strong em{text-transform:uppercase;font-style:normal;font-weight:bolder;background:#FFF;color:red}b{font-weight:700}.warning{text-transform:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:bolder;background:#FFF;color:red}del{text-decoration:line-through;background:#F66}ins{text-decoration:underline;background:#FF0}address{font-style:normal;letter-spacing:.1em;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;margin:1.58em 0;padding:0}acronym{font-variant:small-caps;letter-spacing:.1em}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,dt,th,thead,tfoot{color:#000;background:#FFF}#colophon{display:none}col,colgroup,table,tbody,td,tr{color:#000;text-decoration:none;background:#FFF;border-color:#000;border-style:none}a:link{text-decoration:none;font-weight:700;color:#C00;background:#ffc}a:visited{text-decoration:none;font-weight:700;color:#999;background:#ffc}a:active{text-decoration:none;font-weight:700;color:red;background:#FC0}a:hover{text-decoration:none;color:#C00;background:#FC0}a.offsite{text-decoration:none;font-weight:400;color:#C00;background:#ffc}a,address,blockquote,cite,code,dd,del,dfn,div,dl,dt,em,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,iframe,img,kbd,li,object,ol,p,q,samp,small,span,strong,ul,var,applet,b,big,center,dir,font,hr,i,menu,pre,s,strike,tt,u,abbr,acronym,bdo,button,fieldset,ins,label{border-top:0;border-bottom:0;vertical-align:baseline;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-align:left;float:none;clear:none;list-style-position:outside;margin:0;padding:0}h5{border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-align:left;margin:1.17em 0 .33em;padding:0}p{border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-indent:0;margin:.75em 0;padding:0}dd{border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;margin:0 0 .75em 1.58em;padding:0}li{border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;margin:0 0 0 3.16em;padding:0}div,center{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;border-top:0;border-bottom:0}.stb{margin-top:2.17em;margin-bottom:.75em;padding-top:2.17em;padding-bottom:0;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-style:solid}.mtb{margin-top:3.08em;margin-bottom:.75em;padding-top:3.08em;padding-bottom:0;border-top:.1em;border-bottom:0;border-style:solid}.ltb{margin-top:4.34em;margin-bottom:.75em;padding-top:4.34em;padding-bottom:0;border-top:.25em;border-bottom:0;border-style:solid}col,colgroup,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,tr{border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;float:none;clear:none;margin:0;padding:0}address,blockquote,dl,fieldset,form,ol,p,ul,dir,hr,menu,pre{margin-left:0;margin-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;border-left:0;border-right:0}blockquote{margin-left:1.58em;margin-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;border-left:0;border-right:0}center{margin-left:0;margin-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-align:left}i,var,cite,dfn,.note{font-style:italic}div > p:first-child,body > p:first-child,td > p:first-child,h1 + p,h2 + p,h3 + p,h4 + p,h5 + p,h6 + p,div + p,p.initial{border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;text-align:left;text-indent:0;margin:.75em 0;padding:0}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th{line-height:1.33em}blockquote,fieldset,form,ul,ol,dl,dir,menu,.subhead{margin-top:.75em;margin-bottom:.75em;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;border-top:0;border-bottom:0}dt,ul ul,ol ol,li address,li dl,li ol,li p,li ul,li dir,li hr,li menu,li pre,li h1,li h2,li h3,li h4,li h5,li h6,dd address,dd dl,dd ol,dd p,dd ul,dd dir,dd hr,dd menu,dd pre,dd h1,dd h2,dd h3,dd h4,dd h5,dd h6{border-top:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;border-right:0;margin:0;padding:0}table,td,caption{text-align:left}
#adsense {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Animated Bézier Curves - Jason Davies</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../media/style.css">
    <script src="../media/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../media/js/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="author" content="Jason Davies">
    <style>
      .curve, .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 1px;
      }
      .curve {
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 3px;
      }
      .control {
        fill: #ccc;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: .5px;
      }
      .t, .controltext {
        font-size: .6em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Animated Bézier Curves</h1>
    <p>Play with the control points to modify the curves!</p>
    <div id="vis">
      <script src="animated-bezier.js"></script>
    </div>
    <p>
    These animations illustrate how a parametric <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_Curve">Bézier curve</a> is constructed.
    The parameter <em>t</em> ranges from 0 to 1.
    In the simplest case, a first-order Bézier curve, the curve is a straight line between the control points.
    </p>
    <p>
    For a second-order or quadratic Bézier curve, first we find two intermediate points that are <em>t</em> along the lines between the three control points.
    Then we perform the same interpolation step again and find another point that is <em>t</em> along the line between those two intermediate points.
    Plotting this last point yields a quadratic Bézier curve.
    The same steps can be repeated for higher orders.
    </p>
    <p>
    Written using the <a href="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/">D3 visualisation library</a>.
    Suggested by <a href="http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mbostock/">Mike Bostock</a> and inspired by a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_Curve#Constructing_B.C3.A9zier_curves">similar animation on Wikipedia</a>.
    <p>Requires a SVG-capable browser e.g. <a
      href="http://www.mozilla.org/firefox/">Mozilla Firefox</a>, WebKit (<a
      href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Google Chrome</a>, <a
      href="http://www.apple.com/safari/">Safari</a> &amp;c.) or Internet Explorer 9+.
  </body>
</html>

<p class="copyright">&copy; <a href="http://www.jasondavies.com/">Jason Davies</a> | <a href="../privacy/">Privacy Policy</a>.

<p><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-2911491153890039" data-ad-slot="2029654015"></ins>

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
window.google_analytics_uacct = "UA-54563-3";
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-54563-3']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
setTimeout(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
}, 1);
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```